# In AutoMapper, how can I globally state that I *never* want property to be set in descendant classes?

Tags: c#, automapper

When calling `Services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>`  how can I specify globally that I *never* want the `Timestamp` property to be mapped into on any descendants of my `AggregateRoot` class?

I have tried the following

```cs
private static void AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
        cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p =>
        {
            var setMethod = p.GetSetMethod(true);
            return setMethod is not null && setMethod.IsPublic;
        },
        typeof(Services).Assembly);
}
```

But this is also evaluated for the property being read, so if I make my Setter private on `AggregateRoot` (the class I never want to update) then AutoMapper will also never map **from** that property.

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AAutoMapper%2FAutoMapper%20AddGlobalIgnore&type=code

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu That won't work because it ignores *all* properties named `Timestamp`. I only want to avoid writing *to* AggregateRoot.Timestamp

Comment: What does that mean? Update your question with more details.

Comment: I never want to write to .Timestamp property of any class descending from AggregateRoot (my domain entities). I *do* want to continue reading from them and copying their values into DTOs.